# Customized legend for RadChart

Tags: asp.net, charts, telerik

How can i customize the text in legend. am using `telerik` tools. how can i change the legend text from the back end? c# or vb.net code is enough. as per the customer requirement i need to display combined text from x axis and y axis are to be displayed in the legend. following is the code am using for this.

```
                <telerik:radchart id="radchart_teamchart" autolayout="true" charttitle-appearance-fillstyle-fillsettings-imagealign="Center"
                    chartimageformat="Png" charttitle-visible="true" seriesorientation="Vertical"
                    width="900px" defaulttype="Bubble" runat="server" skin="Vista" autotextwrap="true"
                    intelligentlabelsenabled="true">
                    <ChartTitle TextBlock-Text="My  New Customer Status">
                    </ChartTitle>
                    <Series>
                        <telerik:ChartSeries DataYColumn="noofcustomer" Name="Order" Type="Bar" Appearance-BarWidthPercent="10">
                            <Appearance LabelAppearance-Visible="false">
                                <TextAppearance TextProperties-Font="Cambria, 8.25pt" Position-AlignedPosition="TopLeft">
                                </TextAppearance>

                                <FillStyle MainColor="DarkOrange" SecondColor="WhiteSmoke" FillType="Gradient">
                                </FillStyle>
                                <PointMark Visible="True" Border-Width="2" Border-Color="DarkKhaki" Dimensions-AutoSize="false"
                                    Dimensions-Height="10px" Dimensions-Width="6px">
                                    <FillStyle MainColor="Red" FillType="solid">
                                    </FillStyle>
                                </PointMark>
                                <LineSeriesAppearance Width="6"></LineSeriesAppearance>
                            </Appearance>
                        </telerik:ChartSeries>
                    </Series>
                    <PlotArea>
                        <XAxis DataLabelsColumn="month" AxisLabel-Visible="true" AxisLabel-TextBlock-Text="Month"
                            AxisLabel-TextBlock-Appearance-TextProperties-Color="Brown">
                            <Appearance>
                                <TextAppearance TextProperties-Font="Arial, 8.25pt, style=Bold" Dimensions-Paddings="0.5px">
                                </TextAppearance>
                                <LabelAppearance RotationAngle="270">
                                </LabelAppearance>
                            </Appearance>
                        </XAxis>
                        <YAxis AxisMode="Normal" MaxItemsCount="7" AxisLabel-Visible="true" AxisLabel-TextBlock-Text="No Of Cusotmers"
                            AxisLabel-TextBlock-Appearance-TextProperties-Color="Brown">
                            <Appearance>
                                <TextAppearance TextProperties-Font="Arial, 8.5pt, style=Bold">
                                </TextAppearance>
                            </Appearance>
                        </YAxis>
                    </PlotArea>
                    <Legend Visible="true" ></Legend>
                </telerik:radchart>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that's what a legend is for and thus, I do not think you can do this.

I would advise that you first go through the control documentation and explore the available properties to see whether something is useful for you:

- http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/chart-styling-custom-appearance-properties.html
- http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/chart-styling-elements.html
- http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/chart-legenddisplaymode.html - note the ItemLabels option that puts the items in the legend
- http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/chart-legend.html - there are also some options on building custom legends, so this can help

Another idea is to build a custom legend from your data source. You can see a sample approach here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/functionality/custombarcolor/defaultcs.aspx even though the chart is the current RadHtmlChart control (RadChart is deprecated in favor of this newer chart control).